# Reusability of neural network architecture

Tags: neural-networks

I have created a neural network architecture by considering the data for one study area. Have performed grid-search to tune almost all the hyperparameters of the model. I want to use the same network architecture (without any hyperparameter tuning) on the data of another geographical area for the same topic/ problem.

What I am intended to do is, take the same architecture and train the model with the data of the new area. Later I want to show that even without changing the model architecture the same can be applied to other geographical areas also.

**Is this valid, logical, and understandable work?**

I could not find any resource or paper online that has done a similar thing. All I could find is transfer learning. But I don't think this can be termed transfer learning.

Comment: Your question seems more appropriate for [ai.se].

Comment: "valid, logical, and understandable" sounds like it is requesting opinions.  Do you have a specific, concrete technical question?